# Sending message from background.js to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

I have a background page and a content script.  the content script has this code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ getSetting: { setting: "hideAuth" } }, function (hide) {
    // this should be executed after 'respond(setting)' in the backgroud page
});
```

The background page has this code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, respond) {
    if (msg["getSetting"]) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(msg.getSetting.setting, function (setting) {
            respond(setting); // this should callback to the content script
            });
        });
    }
});
```

However, the response callback in the content script is never executed.  I've tried the run-around of querying the current tab and sending a message back manually but the tab still does not receive the message.  Has anyone dealt with this before?  Is there another way to to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling the `respond` function asynchronously (i.e. inside the callback of `chrome.storage.sync.get`, you should add `return true;` in your `onMessage` listener callback:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, respond) {
    ...
    return true;
});
```

Quoting **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-onMessage-sendResponse)**:

*This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until `sendResponse` is called).*

Comment: Well that works like a charm, but now I'm getting `cannot call method 'disconnect' of null` from the `extensions::event_bindings` code.  Is there a way to manually disconnect before that code catches it?

Comment: Where are you calling disconnect ? `disconnect` is meant for persistent connections only, not for simple, one-time message passing. You don't need it - just use the code above (nothing more is needed).

Comment: That's just the thing.  I'm not.  It's getting called by some internal code that I don't control.  Which means I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: This is strange because I ran the same code (from above) and there was no such error. If you could post the whole code somewhere, I could take a look. Posting the exact stack trace in its entirety might help as well.

Comment: Try attaching a debugger to it.  I just realized it only occurs when I hit a breakpoint within the content script's response callback.