# Get value from local storage in reponse to chrome extension message

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In chrome extension I need `background.js` to answer a message with current value of local storage, but:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.msg == 'is_hidden'){
            chrome.storage.local.get('is_hidden',function(is_hidden){
                if(typeof is_hidden !== 'undefined'){
                    sendResponse(is_hidden);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

... does not work. Doesn't send response.

But this does:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.msg == 'kiss me'){
            sendResponse('*kiss*');
        }
    }
);
```

Seems like `sendResponse` that is in callback of `storage.local.get` loses it's context...

How do I make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent)

Comment: thank you, that saved my day! Should I delete it?