# Not able to access chrome.runtime in iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Trying to access `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in an `iframe`, but it is showing that

> `chrome.runtime` is `undefined`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("kbfjlfcddgkokfgifbohnjfpcnkknpbf", { getVersion: true },
    function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Comment: What error are you getting, please specify it? [Link of similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266192/accessing-iframe-from-chrome-extension?lq=1)

Comment: i have alredy put the error i am getting

Comment: Have you checked the link?

Comment: yes tat is diffrent issue my issue is chrome.runtime value is undefined inside iframe js

Comment: [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226216/chrome-extension-sending-message-from-iframe-to-event-page-then-to-content-scrip)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207129/why-is-chrome-runtime-undefined), if you're inserting JavaScript into a page with a `<script>` tag, it executes in the page's context.

> Sometimes [it is desirable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script): that's the only way to access page-level JavaScript objects.
>
> But in your case it means that the code does not have access to Chrome APIs, as it is "the same" as the page's code.
>
> You need to look into communicating between [page-level and context scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739774/chrome-extension-passing-object-from-page-to-context-script/26740141#26740141), or between [page-level and background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140443/executing-code-at-page-level-from-background-js-and-returning-the-value/26141393#26141393) (spoiler, in most cases needs a context script proxy anyway).

Also from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234623/why-is-chrome-runtime-undefined-in-the-content-script), by adding a breakpoint, or debugger statement, it causes that value to be undefined. Try to refresh the page then open after page is loaded and see if the `chrome.runtime` works correctly.