# Chrome extension XMLHttpRequest with sendResponse

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, content-script

I have a problem using xmlHttpRequest and sendResponse at the same time.

I don't know why but when I set my variable in the x.onload, I get the response "undefined", if I set the variable outside the x.onload, I get the correct value.

See an example of my code below:

**content scrypt :**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({MessageTest: "something"}, function(response) {alert(response.msg);});
```

**event page :**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   var tableauTest = [];

   var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
   x.open('GET', 'http://monsite/page.php');
   x.onload = function() {
       tableauTest[1] = "test"; // not working here

   };
   // if a put tableauTest[1] = "test"; here, it's working
   x.send();
    sendResponse({
       msg: tableauTest[1]
   }); 
 });
```

I tried to put `return true;` ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent)) but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Yes, you tried. You have another conceptual error here with async code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron You need to move `sendResponse` inside `onload` as well.

Comment: Please note: I have re-closed the question with another duplicate, as it seems to be your main problem. But you should still take http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent in consideration: to call `sendResponse` asynchronously you need to return true.

Comment: thank you very much! it's working, I needed both, return true and put sendResponse inside onload