# Difference between runtime.sendMessage and port.postMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension and about to implement some message passing between my background page and the content script, it will require about 3 messages  (content -> background -> content -> background) which all occur in a synchronized order.

I'm not sure what message passing API i should use for this since i don't really understand the difference between the Port API and the normal `chrome.runtime` API.  is there something i can't do with the `runtime.sendmessage` that i can do with the `Port.postMessage`? any major differences that might make me choose one over the other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Port is a reusable, bidirectional connection.

Single messages follow the same scheme, and don't care about the state between invocations:

`sendMessage` -> `onMessage` (optionally ->) `sendResponse` -> callback of `sendMessage`

You can do most anything by that scheme.

There are maybe three aspects of Ports that make them interesting that I can think of.

1. `sendMessage` is a *broadcast* operation.

   In case of `runtime.sendMessage`, it's sent to *all* active pages that are part of the extension. Oftentimes, only one will listen (the background page), but everyone will receive it. So if you have, say, a popup, or an options page open - everyone receives that. You could use a Port to save a tiny bit of resources, or isolate an instance of a page.

   In case of `tabs.sendMessage`, it will by default send to *all frames* within that tab. You can specify a `frameId` *if you know it*, but suppose you don't, and you're broadcasting to all frames, then determine which frame is correct - you can maintain a Port to that frame.
2. An open Port keeps an [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) awake. This can be useful if you're doing something asynchronous that risks unloading the Event Page. This is also a disadvantage if you don't really care about the Event Page staying awake - it prevents the improvement provided by
3. A Port is a "death alarm": in case the context that's on the other end ceases to exist (e.g. the page with the context script was unloaded), you'll be notified by `onDisconnect`.

Unless you need any of the above, you can go with the simpler `sendMessage`-`onMessage` communication.

For your purposes, it would be two calls to `sendMessage` from the content script (as it initiates the connection) and replies from background in `sendResponse`. Don't forget the [nuance about async responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent) if you need it.

Comment: it really is a nu(is)ance isn't it

Comment: @minj What, `return true`? No, it makes sense you have to differentiate "I won't respond" and "I will respond some indeterminate time later".

Comment: Why does the platform care anyway? If this is related to GC that is what `WeakMap` is for.