# Chrome Extension sendResponse callback value not being sent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, callback

I'm coding a chrome extension that interacts with gmail api (chrome 45 is my version) and I am having issues sending a message from the background.js to my content-script.  The async aspect is where the issue lies.  How can I get the message to be sent after the callback?

```
//---------in content script---------
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ messageId: _id }, function (response) {    
    console.log('the respose.messagePayload is: ' + response.messagePayload); 
});

//---------in background script---------
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    getMessage('me', request.messageId, function (payload) {
        //i want to send my response here
        //this executes and grabs the payload of data from the api, but isn't sending back the message to the content-script
        sendResponse({ messagePayload: payload }); 
    });
    //this synchronous call sends a message to the content-script
    //sendResponse({ messagePayload: "payload" });
    return true;
});

function getMessage(userId, messageId,callback) {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
        'userId': userId,
        'id': messageId
    });
    request.execute(callback);
}
```

[Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent)

Comment: Are you certain that the callback with `payload` executes? Can you confirm that with logging?

Comment: @Xan I can confirm that portion works with logging.  I have code to add it to localStorage and read from localStorage, but this is a workaround as I want to send the object in sendResponse 'localStorage.setItem(request.messageId, JSON.stringify(payload));
          sendResponse({ messagePayload: payload });'

Comment: @pacopicorico You can use the 'chrome.storage' API to store your response as object rather than using the stringify. Did you try the second approach I posted, I think that will work fine and save you from storing it to the local storage.

Comment: @NikhilSharma your suggestion did not work. It presents the same issue I am trying to find a solution for.

Comment: @pacopicorico If you are getting the response from the gmail API and your localstorage workaround is working, then what I suggested should work. Can you post what error you are getting or post the logs from both background script and content script while sending and receiving the messages.

Answer (score -1):

You should be sending the `sendResponse` function in your callback.

```
getMessage('me', request.messageId, sendResponse);
```

Then execute this when your `getMessage` call completes.

```
function getMessage(userId, messageId, sendResponse) {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
        'userId': userId,
        'id': messageId
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        sendResponse({messagePayload: response.payload});
    });
}
```

**Another Possible Solution:**

1. Get the `tab id` from the `sender` object.
2. Instead of the callback function just send the tab id to your `getMessage` function.
3. Now, your callback function within the `getMessage` function would send back the payload to your content script.
4. Add a similar `onMessage` listener in your content script that will receive your payload and then do what you want to do with the payload.

Your code would be like:

```
//---------in background script---------
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender,sendResponse) {
    getMessage('me', request.messageId, sender.tab.id);
});

function getMessage(userId, messageId, tabId) {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
        'userId': userId,
        'id': messageId
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {
        // Whatever response you want to sent
        // Below URL explains your response object
        // https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource
        // Assuming you want to send payload
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {messagePayload: response.payload});
    });
}

//---------in content script---------
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ messageId: _id });

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender,sendResponse) {
    // Just to verify that the request is from the getMessage callback
    // Because this will listen to all request from your extension
    if (request.messagePayload) {
        console.log('the respose.messagePayload is: ' + request.messagePayload);
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: First solution is snake oil - closures will take care of this. Second solution is dodging the problem and won't work well with iframes; also, has errors in it.