# Google's Chrome extension messaging example code gets response undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Google's documentation on Chrome extension development has [information on passing messages between a background script and a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). I'm trying the example code:

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });
});
```

content_script.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting == "hello")
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
        //return true;
    });
```

They don't include a manifest file, so I created one (and three icons):

```
{
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js", "content_script.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": ["content_script.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    } ],
    "description": "Test passing messages between a background script and a content script using Google's example code.",
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/icon_16x16.png",
        "48": "img/icon_48x48.png",
        "128": "img/icon_128x128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Google Chrome extension messaging",
    "permissions": ["notifications"],
    "version": "2017.8.25"
}
```

But when I load this extension, the Console reports:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'farewell' of undefined at
>   chrome-extension://ibocemgcnbijkacfkpokffkfkinmenlc/background.js:3:29

I searched online for other cases of the response being undefined, and a few [sources recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent) adding `return true;`. I tried that, but it made no difference (in the code above, it's commented out).

Can anyone see how I could get this working? Thanks!

Comment: I can't see how your content_script is going to end up being injected into any tab - unless I'm missing something, shouldn't you have a `"content_scripts"` in your manifest?

Comment: or perhaps a `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in the background.js - the content_script has to get "in" the content somehow

Comment: I do have a `content_scripts.js` in the manifest. I'm new to Chrome extensions, so I could be wrong, but I assume if additional code were needed, Google would have included it.

Comment: no, you have a file called `content_script.js` in the `background` property - `content_script.js` isn't a *special name* - perhaps you need to read more about `manifest.json`

Comment: Yes, I wasn't thinking `content_script.js` is a special name and thus added to the background page automatically. That's why I included it in the `background` property. The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) state that "A background page will be generated by the extension system that includes each of the files listed in the scripts property." So by listing `content_script.js`, isn't that sufficient to make it part of the background page?

Comment: oh, so you want content_script in background - I thought you wanted it injected into a tab

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to include a file named content_script in the background page. It's not an actual content script, it runs in the same background page, not in a web page, and it won't receive messages sent from the same background page context. This is why you get an undefined value. Continue reading the documentation about the content scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback. (I have been trying to find complete documentation on content scripts, but the Google docs seem quite sparse.) So the [example code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) is incomplete? In other words, it is missing some additional code for adding the content script to the web page?

Comment: The code in [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) assumes that you have read and apply the information in the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview) and [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). In particular, [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) provides information on how to inject content scripts into the page.

Comment: My initial manifest file was missing a "content_scripts" property, so I added it now, to inject `content_scripts.js` into the tab. Unfortunately, the code still gets the same results of the response being undefined.