# chrome.runtime.sendMessage API is not getting the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension. I am using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` API to send a URL to another js file. When I receive the URL in other file through `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addlistener(function(sent,sender,sendResponse){...})`. I call another method or function `checkUrl(url){...}` to which I pass the URL sent by the other file as a message. and this function returns the Ajax call to that URL. And then I use `.then() promise` in the scope where I have called the `checkUrl(url){...}` function. I get the response perfectly and after displaying the response in the console, I send that response back to the sender file where I got the message from. But I am not getting any response on the content script I don't know if I have mistaken something...

**Content Script Code to send Message**

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"postUrl",mess:url},function(r){
   console.log(r.res);
});
```

**Script I am getting the message and then trying to send response back**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(sent,sender,sendResponse){
 alert("message recieved");
 var str;
 switch(sent.type){
  case "postUrl":{
        checkUrl(sent.mess).then(function(r){
           console.log("Promise Test : " + r);
           sendResponse({res:r})
     });
     break;
  }
 }
});


function checkUrl(url){
    return $.ajax({
       method:"GET",
       url:"http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/connections.php?fbPostUrl=true",
       data:{
        url:url
       }
    })

}
```

Comment: You are not returning a value in checkUrl. The jQuery ajax is asynchron and you can not use it to send a response like that. Your ajax function should have a complete callback function, that uses sendMessage itself to send data back to your first script.

Comment: How would I do that, do you have any reference !

Comment: Also this code is not valid `{type:"postUrl",mess:url},` what is `mess` and `url`?

Comment: @jukben I am just passing a JSON object as a message

Comment: @Nadeem Extend your ajax call with a `success` property: `$.ajax({..., success: function(result) {chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result)});`. In your first script, you have to add a chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener to handle the message send once he ajax finished.

Comment: @DB the first script is wrote inside another function which get called by another function so even if I put the listener script inside that, I will require to call that function and that is not possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent)

Comment: Thank you so much @wOxxOm it worked for me !