# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. when using message passing API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build a password manager extension for Google Chrome. I want my background script to check for URLs matching with the login URLs of different websites and when it does match, I want to send the credentials of the user to the content script which will autofill the username and password fields. But I am getting the "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." error

I have seen similar questions and the major answer was to disable the other extensions and try again. I disabled all the extensions and tried, but still getting the same error. I also saw that long-lived connections solve this error, but I don't want to use a long-lived connection as this is a one time message

background.js

```
/*Listen for changes in URL */
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){

    if(changeInfo.url){
        console.log(changeInfo.url);
        chrome.storage.local.get(null,function(ans){
            console.log("local storage",ans);
         });
        chrome.storage.local.get(['loggedIn'],function(answer){
            console.log('logged in answer is',answer);
            console.log('logged in answer is',answer.loggedIn);
            if(answer.loggedIn===true){

                console.log("user logged in")
                /* Check whether the user is logged in and the url is in the user credential urls*/
                chrome.storage.local.get(['urls'],function(result){
                    console.log("stored urls",result.urls,"current url",changeInfo.url);
                    if(result.urls.includes(changeInfo.url)){
                        console.log("matching url");
                        console.log("matching url",changeInfo.url);
                        var urlIndex = result.urls.indexOf(changeInfo.url);
                        console.log('index',urlIndex);



                       console.log("main tab id is",tabId)
                       console.log("tab is",tab);

                       chrome.storage.local.get(['credentials'],function(result){
                            console.log(result);
                            var username = result.credentials[urlIndex].username;
                            var password = result.credentials[urlIndex].password;
                            console.log('username',username,password)

                            var msg = {
                                username : username,
                                password : password
                            }

                            /* Get the credentials for that site and send it to the content script autoFill.js */    

                            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId,{args: msg},function(response) {
                                console.log(tabId,tab.url);
                                console.log(response);
                            });
                        });


                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                console.log("user not logged in");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

content_script.js

```
console.log("content script is running");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("message recieved");
    console.log(request.args);
    var args=request.args;
    console.log('args',args);


    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    console.log(forms);

    for(let form of forms){
        console.log(form);
        for (let index = 0; index < form.length; index++) {
            const element = form.elements[index];
            //console.log(element);
            if(element.type==='password'){
                element.value=args.password;
                console.log(element.value);
                for (let reverseIndex = index-1; reverseIndex >= 0; reverseIndex--) {
                    const element = form.elements[reverseIndex];
                    if(element.type==='text'){
                        element.value=args.username;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    sendResponse("success");
    return true;
});
```

I am expecting the content script to receive the message and make the parameters available in the current tab. So any help about how to fix this error is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It happens when a tab didn't have the content script running at the time the message was sent. For example your content script is declared without "run_at": "document_start". Or you reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page and didn't reload the web page or didn't reinject the content scripts manually via chrome.tabs.executeScript. A typical solution is to make the content script send a message and process the response in the callback. Your background script will have an onMessage listener and will [return true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077854) to keep the channel open.

Comment: Thanks.Declaring the content script to  "run_at": "document_start" in manifest.json solved the issue.